# How can we send OAuth2.0 with axios in React js

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, axios

I am working on one authentication problem where i have to implement OAuth2.0 authentication for my React App. Is there any way that i can use that authentication with Axios Promise based library???

Answer (score 12):

You will have to pass your Token in the header.

See below;

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost/api/',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'basic '+ token}
});

instance.get('/path')
.then(response => {
    return response.data;
})
```

OR

Set an Authorization cookie in the browser once you get your token.
The browser will always send the Authorization cookie in each request made to the server. You won't have to pass it through Axios get/post.

**UPDATE:**

In order to get the access token from the oAuth server, pass the client_id, client_secret, scope and grant_type as follows;

```
var axios = require("axios");

axios.request({
  url: "/oauth/token",
  method: "post",
  baseURL: "http://sample.oauth.server.com/",
  auth: {
    username: "myUsername", // This is the client_id
    password: "myPassword" // This is the client_secret
  },
  data: {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "public"    
  }
}).then(respose => {
  console.log(respose);  
});
```

I am assuming that you are using grant_type = "client_credentials", if not, then based on the grant_type you use, you will have to also change the request parameters accordingly.

Comment: But what should i do to get that token with OAUTH?  I have an authorization URL with client_id, scope and other request parameters. How can i achieve the token in my localstorage by hitting that URL?

Comment: Is it a way to store the token in localStorage if the access_token is coming in URL? I have tried the JavaScript "window.location.hash" with multiple split operation to store in local storage. I think it is not an optimized way!!

Comment: This fails with 400 every time.  `axios-oauth-client` is good for oauth, but it's not very test friendly.  I would like to simply use `axios` for this, but have found it impossible to form a valid request using it.