# Axios is not working to get access token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, axios

i have axios call to get the bearer token it is oauth2.0 but for some reason it is failing same call is working in postman.

index.js

```
export async function getESLAccessToken(apiConfig: any) {
    const _body = {
        grant_type: apiConfig.authOptions.body.grant_type,
        client_id: apiConfig.authOptions.credentials.sdk_voyage.clientId,
        client_secret: apiConfig.authOptions.credentials.sdk_voyage.clientSecret,
        scope: apiConfig.authOptions.body.scope
    };
    const _headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "appName": "Blink",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Length": 163
    };
    const request = {
        method: 'POST',
         _body,
        headers: _headers
    };

    try {
        const resp = await axios.post('https://auth/oauth2/token',
        request);
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        throw err;
    }
}
```

This is how request building for axios

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "_body": {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "abc",
    "client_secret": "xyz",
    "scope": "APPPII APPPHI"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "appName": "Blink",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": 163
  }
}
```

Error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

Postman working request and response

```
POST https://auth/oauth2/token
200
163 ms
POST /auth/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1

Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d90ccc33-1d77-4502-9a41-74080dd3d7a5
Host: qaapih8.corp.cvscaremark.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 163
Request Body
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=abc&client_secret=xyz&scope=APPPII%20APPPHI
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Response Body

```
{ "token_type":"Bearer", "access_token":"token returned", "expires_in":3600, "consented_on":164684, "scope":"APPPII APPPHI" }
```

Comment: Can you also share the working example in Postman?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we send OAuth2.0 with axios in React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487260/how-can-we-send-oauth2-0-with-axios-in-react-js)

Comment: @Tasos addesd postman requesrt and response

Comment: I dont think "body" uses an `_` prefix

Comment: Actually there is no "body" in the axios docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

Comment: @Tasos Indeed. They use "data" instead

Comment: Keep in mind that axios also has an `auth` prop to authenticate with something like oauth2.0. This is what I would do instead of setting the custom headers

Comment: @Tasos i tried passing data: _body it still returns the same error , can you share some example axios auth prop authenticate

Comment: Try to remove the method field, as you are using axios post. Also keep the code as 
data: _body and try to spread the object like so ...request

Comment: @hussain see this it might help you even though it is for react, ti's still JS code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487260/how-can-we-send-oauth2-0-with-axios-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `axios.post` function should be the request body. And the third argument should be the Axios request config object (Which you can set your headers). [Axios POST Requests](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)

In your case, the code should be like:

```
const body = {
  grant_type: apiConfig.authOptions.body.grant_type,
  client_id: apiConfig.authOptions.credentials.sdk_voyage.clientId,
  client_secret: apiConfig.authOptions.credentials.sdk_voyage.clientSecret,
  scope: apiConfig.authOptions.body.scope
};

const myHeaders = {
  // add your headers here
}

const response = await axios.post(
  'https://auth/oauth2/token',
  body,
  { headers: myHeaders }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
const request = {
    method: 'POST',
     _body,
    headers: _headers
};
```

with:

```
const request = {
    method: 'POST',
    data: _body,
    headers: _headers
};
```

As pointed out by the docs in the comments session: https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

Comment: i tried this it didnt work same error